# module 'PyQt5' has no attribute 'QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

![My Code][1]

I installed all the libraries using pip and pip3.

I'm using python 3.8.3 and spyder 4.1.4

when ı writing codes IDE show me all libraries in QtWebEngine but trying to start my code IDE says

"module 'PyQt5' has no attribute 'QtWebEngineWidgets'"
and ı have all QtWebEngineWidgets files in computer.

```
import PyQt5 as py
import sys

app=py.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#app = Py.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = py.QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window = py.QtWidgets.QWidget()



p=py.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(window)
b=py.QtCore.QUrl('https://stackoverflow.com')
p.load(b)
p.show()





window.setGeometry(0, 35, 400, 400)
window.setWindowTitle("Ground Control")
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you installed pyqtwebengine: `python -m pip install pyqtwebengine`?

Comment: yes i tried that :(

Comment: Are you sure your IDE is using the correct python? Try running `python C:/untitled5.py` in the cmd:

Comment: ım sure. but ı think there is an issue about reaching the library and pyqt5 versions but ı didnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
```

pop this in and this should get you further

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please try to `comment` one-line answers!